# PMP Experience Verification

Tags: pmp, user-experience-design

I'm currently studying for the PMP exam and I am wondering if I could use below as experience for the PMP.

2008-2012: 
Title: Manager (Position located in Taiwan)
I managed 2 staff members and organize students to send them to UK to do their masters. Every year, my staff and I handled around 50 students. Below is how the experience relates to PMP:

Initiate:Consult the students to understand what they are looking for, what courses they want to study, their budget, their goals

Plan: Plan the schedule, preparing and writing application documents, applying school, English TOEFL test, university offer dates and accept, accommodation application, visa application, all other documents needed, etc.List out the dates on when to prepare.

Execution: Work with staff, students, universities to work with the plan.

Monitor: Monitor if everything is according to plan, if not, what needs to be changed.

Closing: After everything is done and students received their offer and accepted, sit down with students to consult if everything is what they planned.

From your experience, do you think PMP will accept this experience? I have other experiences, but would need to use this to fulfill my 4500 hours.

Thanks,

Peter

Comment: Only PMI can answer this; all other answers are mere guesses. Having said that, I think it is <em>possible</em> that you will be challenged on the grounds that you're describing an operational process, rather than a project with a discrete outcome.  I think your descriptions *possibly* insulate you, but you may wish to craft your language to emphasize the unique plan/project developed for each student.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PMP Experience Documentation](http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/883/pmp-experience-documentation)

Answer (score 1):

As a commenter said, only PMI can answer this. *However*, having earned been through the PMP process (and having been audited on my experience by PMI) I would say that sounds good. There are lots of types of 'projects' out there: Even a lot of functional managers do bits of PM work here and there. The most important thing I can say is **be honest, and expect to get audited.** If you feel like this was legitimately project-type work, you're probably right. Were you following processes from the PMBOK or other industry standards? If so, then it *certainly* qualifies.

Anecdotally, I had a fair bit of this type of experience on my application. The audit process verified that I did what I said what I had for the most part, and required a letter from my manager or something along those lines. I would focus on being prepared for the test and assume your application will go through.

Answer (score 0):

like others said, you should just be honest and you should have a contact person, whom could acknowledge your information if being audited.

Like others said, you should be prepared for audit anyway, so there is nothing to fear anymore than. For this case you may have a look here, what could be of use for you:

Audit Kit:
☛  http://wren.cf/6o

Regards,

Markus

PS: My application was audited and this helped me a lot ... 
Please don't hesitate to contact me, fi there where any further questions.